# How do I make copy of spreadsheet and save it to particular folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm working with Google App Script. I am trying to:

1. Make a copy of a spreadsheet
2. Give the copy a particular file name, and
3. Save it to a particular folder.

It seems to me that the code below should work, but it doesn't.  It **does** accomplish tasks 1 and 3 - that is, it makes a copy and saves the copy to my desired folder.  However, it does not save the file with the file name I specify.  Instead, it saves it as "Copy of [original spreadsheet filename]." To do this, I am using [`File#makeCopy`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))

(Note: I know this question has been answered before, but I believe it has not been answered since Google sunset the DocList service.)

When I made this simplified MCVE, I found that it works as expected:

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("desired file name", destFolder);
} //END function saveAsSpreadsheet
```

However, my original code does not - the copy's name is wrong:

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var buildingNameAddress = sheet.getRangeByName('buildingNameAddress').getValue();
  Logger.log(buildingNameAddress); //Logs correct string
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(buildingNameAddress, destFolder);
}
```

Comment: this code is correct and works... just tested now.

Comment: As Serge said, works for me too. All 3 tasks accomplished!

Comment: Thanks. You're right, that code works. I simplified my code before posting it. What my code actually looks like is this:                                function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var buildingNameAddress = sheet.getRangeByName('buildingNameAddress').getValue(); Logger.log(buildingNameAddress); //Logs correct string var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(buildingNameAddress, destFolder); }                    @pointNclick @ Serge insas

Comment: Why does code immediately above not work?  Thanks.

Comment: Given that you state the script logs show the expected string value, it probably has properties that prevent it from being used as a Drive filename.

Answer (score 24):

This code works good for me.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your_drive_folder_id"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById("your_drive_source_file_id").makeCopy("particular_file_name", destFolder); 
}
```

Comment: This answer hasn't gotten enough attention...two lines of code, and it copies ALL the workbooks in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the corrected code for your function that worked for me. You were not setting the named range for which I used the method `setNamedRange` and gave it a name. That and changing the variable name to which you were getting the range values to `TestRange`. Also, `getValue()` would only get you one value whereas you needed a range of values hence, used `getValues()` instead. But the rest of the code was fine and worked perfectly.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1:B3');
  sheet.setNamedRange('buildingNameAddress', range);
  var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('buildingNameAddress').getValues(); 
  Logger.log(TestRange); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Test File", destFolder); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make a copy, it only shares the spreadsheet. It doesn't create a new sheet